# How to print rupee symbol in ireport pdf output?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I want to add the rupee symbol in my ireport pdf output. I have added the font `Indian_rupee.ttf` to the build path and installed it but again I am getting the same problem.

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use Unicode Character for 'INDIAN RUPEE SIGN'

For this unicode use font **DejaVu Sans**,
Unicode Character for INR is **&#x20b9** (hex).

if above unicode is not working then try  **&#8377** (decimal).

This usicode is use for HTML, so make sure you are select html as markup.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="520" y="0" width="30" height="20" uuid=""/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="14"/>
        </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression>"&#8377"</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Not working for me with any of the unicodes. Please suggest if any alternate approach is there. Should I add the ttf?

Comment: The issue is I am able to get the symbol in `JRViewer`. However it is not working with `JRPdfExporter`

Answer (score -1):

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="520" y="0" width="30" height="20" uuid=""/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="14"/>
        </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression>"&#8377"</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Using this you can get symbol in JRViewer only.
Same issue I am facing that able to get the symbol in JRViewer. but it is not working with JRPdfExporter. (on pdf not displayed).