# Indian rupee symbol cannot display in pdf that generated by jasperreports?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm using jasperreports-6.0.3 to generate pdf report, but the indian rupee symbol is displayed as empty in the generated pdf file. I tried pdfFontName: Helvetica and pdfEncoding: Cp1252, also tried pdfFontName: Arial and pdfEncoding: Identity-H. Both are not work for me.

The string is displayed correctly in eclipse as:

[image]

But in the generated pdf it displayed as:

[image]

Is there anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you use font extensions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print rupee symbol in ireport pdf output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491557/how-to-print-rupee-symbol-in-ireport-pdf-output) & [Jasper Reports PDF doesn't export cyrillic values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34041619/876298)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports PDF doesn't export cyrillic values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render with a font which supports the Rupee symbol, then it should display. For example [Rupee_Foradian.ttf](https://techwelkin.com/download/rupee-symbol-font/Rupee_Foradian.ttf) or [ITF-Rupee.ttf](https://techwelkin.com/download/rupee-symbol-font/ITF-Rupee.ttf) (Source: [Download Rupee Symbol](https://techwelkin.com/download/rupee-symbol-font/)). Embedding that font might be the key to make it portable (so that it shows on any computer). Modern Hindi fonts should support it as well. And the config for this should be: `<pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>`.

Comment: It just needs to support embedding fonts.